# What the best practices to organize packages for automated tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm, software-quality

I am the only person in QA in my company and I would like to introduce automation test with WebDriver, Cucumber, Java. What is the best way for organize my packages?

### Heading

src/main/java

- com.mycompany.myapp.pageobject
      selenium classes
      elements, pageObject etc/

src/test/resources

- List item

features

src/test/java

com.mycompany.myapp.cucumber    ---StepsDefinition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create your own Test project/solution. In it you can organize the test logic in suites according to your needs. My previous Java test solution was organised like this:

```
[Test project name]
   --- [java] //a core of your .jar files
     --- ui module
     --- services module
     --- DB access module
   --- [test] // a core of your test logic
     --- suites
     --- ui module
     --- services module
     --- DB access module
   --- [environments] //property files
     --- UAT 
     --- SIT
```

Comment: Thank you a lot I just would like to get some ideas